# When you chain a property, do you call it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This question concerns semantics of "property" and "method." I understand that in JavaScript, a variable in an object is a property and a function in an object is a method.

In a Node.js application, I'm passing `process.mainModule.filename` as an argument to `path.dirname()`. `mainModule` is a property of the Process object (as I found in the [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_mainmodule)). Is it correct to say I'm "calling" `mainModule`? Is it a method and a property in this case, or maybe a property that holds a method? (Also wondering the same for `filename`.)

Comment: Properties are usually accessed when read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `mainModule` is a property of `process` and it itself is an object with its own properties. One of them is `filename`.
So it won't be "calling" but rather accessing one of its properties

Hope it helped

Answer (score 2):

If it was a method you would have put `(with, optional, arguments)` after it (or possibly used `.call()` or `.apply()` on it.